# spring framework 3.2 in spring tool suite 3.6

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I downloaded latest Spring Tool Suite from its website i.e. STS 3.6.0 I thought with that I would be getting the latest Spring framework version too but that is not the case.

When I created a new Spring MVC project and open my pom.xml it says that Spring version is 3.1.1

I want to work with 3.2 only.

I am new to java and spring.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try using the 'New Spring Starter' project. Does this give you a more recent version of Spring? The wizard you are using is an older one. The 'New Spring Starter' wizard is a newer one and uses more 'modern' versions of Spring as well as Spring Boot. We keep the old wizard around for the more conservative folks.

Comment: If you are new to Spring you may also be interested in the spring.io guides (https://spring.io/guides#gs) which use spring boot as well (so they work with projects that will look similar to the 'New Spring Starter' setup. You'll probably need the guides since the 'New Spring Starter' .creates an 'empty' project.

Comment: I agree to Kris, please take a look at the more modern way of using Spring with the guides and the Spring Boot way (maybe using the guide to create a RESTful service). If you still want to use the older Spring MVC example with a newer Spring version, just create the project, open the pom.xml file, and change the Spring version that is defined there. The IDE will automatically update the classpath to the new Spring version.